# Qual é a finalidade do ? (ponto de interrogação) ao chamar uma função em Elixir?

Tags: característica-linguagem, convenções-de-nome, elixir

Estou estudando o [módulo](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#any?/2) `Enum` da linguagem Elixir no qual fornece varias funções que permite trabalhar com *enumerables*, entretanto, uma coisa me chamou a atenção na chamada de algumas das funções.

A função `any` quando esta a chamar ela é necessário informar um `?` caso contrario da erro, veja os exemplos:

```
array = [1, 23, 54, 1, 121]
r = Enum.any?(array,
    fn(v) ->
        v > 100
    end
)
IO.puts(r)
```

Saída:

> true

Sem o `?` na chamada da função:

```
r = Enum.any(array,
    fn(v) ->
        v > 100
    end
)
```

Saída:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Enum.any/2 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * any?/1
      * any?/2

    (elixir) Enum.any([1, 23, 54, 1, 121], #Function<1.115443437 in file:main.exs>)
    main.exs:26: (file)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a finalidade do `?` em uma função?
2. Qual é a relação do `?` com a assinatura da função?
3. O que o `?` faz de especial na função?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual é a finalidade do `?` em uma função?

Só estilo de codificação e convenção de nomenclatura.

> Qual é a relação do `?` com a assinatura da função?

Nenhuma real, só uma convencional.

> O que o `?` faz de especial na função?

Na linguagem, nada.

Mas é convencionado que funções que resultam em um valor booleano deve ter seu nome pós-fixado com esse caractere para indicar que é uma indagação que deve ser respondida com um sim ou não. Você pode só não usar, ou usar de forma diferente, mas estará fugindo da recomendação. É só um caractere como outro qualquer no nome.

O erro é só porque não usou o nome completo, se tiver uma função retornando booleano sem o `?` no nome tem que chamar sem o `?`, assim como se uma função `EVerdade` é diferente de `EhVerdade`.

[Documentação](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/naming-conventions.html#trailing-question-mark-foo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O interessante é que nas outras linguagens o ? no final do nome da syntax invalida.

Comment: Sim, na maioria.

Answer (score 4):

A própria documentação do Elixir fala sobre isso em ["Naming Conventions"](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/naming-conventions.html#trailing-question-mark-foo).

### Interrogação?

O ponto de interrogação no Elixir indica que a função retorna um booleano. Veja que não só nas funções, mas também em variáveis.

```
iex> active? = (1 + 1 == 2)
true
```

Note que as cláusulas de guarda do Elixir não possuem essa mesma convenção, porém seguem o estilo do Erlang, com `is_*`, ao invés de `*?`.

```
iex> defmodule Math do
iex>   def double(arg) when is_number(arg) do
iex>     ...
iex>   end
iex>
iex>   def double(arg) when is_list(arg) do
iex>     ...
iex>   end
iex> end
```

As clásulas de guarda acima são definidas com `is_number` e `is_list`, e sem interrogação.

### Exclamação!

O ponto de exclamação no Elixir indica que a função pode gerar uma exceção, ao invés da tupla de erro, que é padrão no Elixir. Veja:

```
File.read("file.txt")
{:ok, "file contents"}
iex> File.read("no_such_file.txt")
{:error, :enoent}

iex> File.read!("file.txt")
"file contents"
iex> File.read!("no_such_file.txt")
** (File.Error) could not read file no_such_file.txt: no such file or directory
```